# How do I get both the child and one upper level parent information by using oracle connect by prior?

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, connect-by, hierarchical-query

I want to get both the child and one upper level parent information by using oracle connect by prior?

For example the folowing query retrieve child info and parent id,

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, LEVEL
  FROM employees
  START WITH employee_id = 100
  CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
```

but I want to get parent info also like

```
  LAST_NAME                 EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID      LEVEL   MANAGER_NAME
 ------------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------------------------
 King                              100                     1         ?
 Cambrault                         148        100          2         ?
 Bates                             172        148          3         ?
 Bloom                             169        148          3         .
 Fox                               170        148          3         .
```

How can I handle this problem, when I applied left join after selecting childs by connect by prior,The objects order is mixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to `prior` values in the select list:

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, LEVEL, prior last_name as manager_name
  FROM employees
  START WITH employee_id = 100
  CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;

LAST_NAME                 EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID      LEVEL MANAGER_NAME            
------------------------- ----------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------
King                              100                     1                          
Kochhar                           101        100          2 King                     
Greenberg                         108        101          3 Kochhar                  
Faviet                            109        108          4 Greenberg                
...
Cambrault                         148        100          2 King                     
Bates                             172        148          3 Cambrault                
Bloom                             169        148          3 Cambrault                
Fox                               170        148          3 Cambrault                
...
```

Comment: Thank yo very much.That's it